# Open Firmware Password complexity

Tags: firmware-password

I couldn't find an Apple doc stating Firmware Password complexity limitations, e.g. length and allowed special characters.

Does anyone know if Apple states this information somewhere?

I don't want to be in a situation where I try to enable a complex password to find out that for some reason I'm locked out and I need to turn to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Support Document [HT1352](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1352) states:

> Use a secure password that contains both numerals and letters in the
>   first eight characters.

I assume from this statement that OF ignores the 9th and succeeding characters in the chosen password, but I haven't tested to see if this is the case. Further down in the document, an image of the Firmware Password Utility window states unambiguously that passwords composed of letters and numbers only should be entered:
[image]

Comment: thank you for that link! The only thing in my question that is unclear is the length of the password, e.g. as you stated if > 8 characters is used and if there is a maximum limit.